# Remove all iframe containing src="some_src.com/....."

Tags: css, iframe, adblock

I am a newbie to javascript. In my browser there is an ad popup that is NOT detected by Adblock super. I want to add it to the block list. The following is the format of the iframe:-

```
IFRAME
[id="dealply-toast-328099"]
[class="dealply-toast dealply-toast-328099"]
[src="http://f.tonginjs.info/TopBarAnimatedWhite.html?#pi=100030081|index=0|b=%2F%2Fs.tonginjs.info%2Fdealdo%2Fshoppingjs4%3Fb%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%3D%3D#rg"
```

I want to remove all the elements in the webpage having src starting with "http://f.tonginjs.info/" [coz I hate this site]. How should I add the query to Adblock super to remove all frames that have this src?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the following attribute selector will do the job:

```
iframe[src^="http://f.tonginjs.info/"]
```

The `^=` in CSS means "starts with." This isn't really a Javascript question, but rather a CSS one.